# Async requests vaadin

Tags: gwt, asynchronous, vaadin

I find no documentation on how to update objects vaadin asynchronously. Can anyone help me? What I need is to render a table and then update the values ​​of a column with a call rather slow, and so I want to make it asynchronous ..

Answer (score 3):

This has been discussed a lot on this [thread](http://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/222759) on the Vaadin forum. You might want to read it, it contains a lot of useful information.

Comment: you are not useful, at least you have to put the link

Answer (score 1):

Just do the updates in another thread. UI modifications from background threads must be synchronized to application object. Add icepush, refresher or proggresbar to get changes from server to client.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Vaadin provides two add-ons for solving this problem: [ServerPush](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/serverpush) and [DontPush](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/dontpush).  Both add-ons can be imported via maven and both support WebSockets as well as fallback solutions for browsers without WebSocket support.  Although ServerPush provides seemingly more features than DontPush, it is lower rated than DontPush, probably because it is more complicated.

For pushing updates to the client DontPush provides a very simple solution that does not require any changes to the web application.  Only the servlet-class in web.xml needs to be replaced by `org.vaadin.dontpush.server.impl.jetty.DontPushServlet` and the widget set has to be updated afterwards via `mvn vaadin:update-widgetset`.  That's all.  Any changes on the server will be automatically pushed to the client.  I successfully tested this add-on with Chrome 14.  Unfortunately, I could not get it working with Firefox 7.

According to the web page of ServerPush the ServerPush add-on should provide this functionality, too.  However, I could not figure out how to setup ServerPush to be working with jetty.  Moreover, it seems to be more complicated in use.  It requires several changes to the web.xml as well as additional configuration files for the atmosphere server.

In contrast to DontPush ServerPush provides also an explicit pushing mechanism which allows to update the GUI manually by calling the `push()` method of a certain pusher component which needs to be added to the main window beforehand.  However, I also failed to get this working.